# PHP PDO Output results outside while {}

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is it possible to output all database results outside of while loop?
I want to use it inside another echo.

```
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT color FROM table WHERE type = :key");
$sql->bindValue(':key', $type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->execute();

while($rows = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {
      $colors = $rows ['color'];

      echo $colors; //Outputs all results
    }

echo $colors; //Outputs only last result
```

Comment: So save it as a variable first outside the loop. What have you tried already?

Comment: you have to learn what is the concat.

Comment: you can use array. put all the data in array and use it outside of loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure just store them to an array:

```
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT color FROM table WHERE type = :key");
$sql->bindValue(':key', $type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->execute();

$colors = [];
while($rows = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {
      $colors[] = $rows ['color'];

    }

print_r($colors)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing the while loop to save to an array you can just get all the results at once as an array with the [PDOStatement::fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) method

```
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT color FROM table WHERE type = :key");
$sql->bindValue(':key', $type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->execute();

$colors = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH));
print_r($colors);
```